# Conditional join based on value of column

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table of addresses with a column for Canadian provinces and another column for US States as well as a column for country.  We support other countries but we treat Canadian and US different.

We have a separate table the is a list of codes, there is a table id and a code value.  So the code table id for Canadian provinces is say 5 and has the 13 values for all the provinces and territories.  The US states are in the same table but with a code table is say 6 and has all 50 states.

I have been asked to write a report that would reference the province or state and I am struggling with a way to change the code table id used in the join to get the province or state description depending on the country code.

Table structure for address (simplified):

```
CNTRY_CD (value 3 is Canada, 22 is US, others exist but only these two are linked tothe code table)
PROV_CD (only has values when country is 3, zero otherwise)
STATE_CD (only has values when country is 22, zero otherwise)
```

Table structure for code tables (simplified):

```
TABLE_ID (provinces are table 5 and states are table 6)
CODE (for table 5 there are 13 values, for table 6 there 50 values)
DESC (the name of the province or state depending on above)
```

If you need additional details just let me know.

**EDIT**
Sample data follows:

| ADDR_ID | PROV_CD | STATE_CD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 3 | NULL |
| 02 | NULL | 25 |
| 03 | NULL | NULL |

| TABLE_ID | CODE | DESC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 3 | Manitoba |
| 5 | 4 | Ontario |
| 6 | 25 | Michigan |
| 6 | 26 | Montana |

**Report**

| JURISDICTION | DESC | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Canada | Manitoba | 123 |
| US | Michigan | 321 |
| Other | Other | 5 |

What has been causing me the most trouble is that the table id is not in the data - it is known only by the column the data comes from.  So if the column is PROV_CD then I know to use code table id 5, if STATE_CD then I know to use code table id 6 but the actual data does not contain the code table id.  Hope that makes sense.

---

This is the closest I have been so far:

Here is redacted source data:

CLIENT_ID ADDR_ID CNTRY_CSN CDN_PROV_CSN US_STE_CSN ADDR_L1_TXT          PVST_NM

---

```
   821   72301       104            0          0 International line 1 NULL   
   821   72302       148            0          1 NULL                 NULL   
   821   72303       221            0         14 NULL                 NULL   
   821   72304        36            9          0 NULL                 NULL   
   821   72305         0            0          0 NULL                 NULL   
   821   72306       221            0         44 NULL                 NULL   
   821   72307        36            9          0 NULL                 NULL   
   821   72308         0            0          0 NULL                 NULL   
   821   72309         0            0          0 NULL                 NULL   
   821   72310         0            0          0 NULL                 NULL   
   822    1481        36            9          0 NULL                 NULL   
   822    1482        36            0          0 NULL                 NULL
```

Here is redacted SQL:

```
SELECT CLIENT_ID, ADDR_ID, CNTRY_CSN, CD_EDESC
FROM CLNT_ADDR
LEFT OUTER JOIN TXSCT
ON CD_TBL_ID = 
    CASE CNTRY_CSN 
        WHEN 36 THEN 10
        WHEN 148 THEN 538
        WHEN 221 THEN 12
        ELSE NULL
    END
AND CSN =
    CASE
        WHEN CDN_PROV_CSN > 0 THEN CDN_PROV_CSN
        WHEN US_STE_CSN > 0 THEN US_STE_CSN
        ELSE NULL
    END 
WHERE CLIENT_ID IN (821, 822) 
WITH UR;
```

Here is the result I get:

CLIENT_ID ADDR_ID CNTRY_CSN CD_EDESC

---

```
   821   72301       104 NULL
   821   72302       148 Aguascalientes  
   821   72302       148 Aguascalientes  
   821   72303       221 Idaho           
   821   72304        36 Ontario         
   821   72305         0 NULL
   821   72306       221 Texas           
   821   72307        36 Ontario         
   821   72308         0 NULL
   821   72309         0 NULL
   821   72310         0 NULL
   822    1481        36 Ontario         
   822    1482        36 NULL
```

Address id 72302 is repeated, don't know why.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: The answer looks simple enough, but the details are not clear. Please add a few rows of sample data abd the expected result.

Comment: Don't know why the tables got butchered - the preview showed them just fine.  Sorry.
Apparently you have to leave at least one blank line between the preceding text and the start of any table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as is.
Two ways to resolve it - with 2 `left joins` (comment out all lines until the end starting from the one with `JOIN` and uncomment 2 lines with `LEFT JOIN`, comment out the line with `C.DESC` and uncomment one with `COALESCE`) or 1 `inner join` (as is below).

```
WITH 
  ADDRESS 
  (
      CNTRY_CD --(value 3 is Canada, 22 is US, others exist but only these two are linked tothe code table)
    , PROV_CD  --(only has values when country is 3, zero otherwise)
    , STATE_CD --(only has values when country is 22, zero otherwise)
  ) 
  AS
  (
    VALUES
      ( '3', 'P1',   '')
    , ( '3', 'P2',   '')  
    , ('22',   '', 'S1')
    , ('22',   '', 'S2')  
  )
, CODE
  (
      TABLE_ID --(provinces are table 5 and states are table 6)
    , CODE     --(for table 5 there are 13 values, for table 6 there 50 values)
    , DESC     --(the name of the province or state depending on above)  )
  ) 
  AS
  (
    VALUES
      (5, 'P1', 'Canadian Province1')
    , (5, 'P2', 'Canadian Province2') 
    -- Just to show, that the same code may be for different countries
    -- but the statement works correctly
    , (5, 'S1', 'Canadian Province3')  

    , (6, 'S1', 'US State1')
    , (6, 'S2', 'US State2')  
    , (6, 'P1', 'US State3')  
  )
SELECT 
  A.*
--, COALESCE (C.DESC, U.DESC) AS DESC
, C.DESC
FROM ADDRESS A
--LEFT JOIN CODE C ON C.CODE = A.PROV_CD  AND (C.TABLE_ID, A.CNTRY_CD) = (5,  '3')
--LEFT JOIN CODE U ON U.CODE = A.STATE_CD AND (U.TABLE_ID, A.CNTRY_CD) = (6, '22')
JOIN CODE C ON 
   (C.CODE = A.PROV_CD  AND (C.TABLE_ID, A.CNTRY_CD) = (5,  '3'))
OR (C.CODE = A.STATE_CD AND (C.TABLE_ID, A.CNTRY_CD) = (6, '22'))
```

The result is:

| CNTRY_CD | PROV_CD | STATE_CD | DESC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | P1 |  | Canadian Province1 |
| 3 | P2 |  | Canadian Province2 |
| 22 |  | S1 | US State1 |
| 22 |  | S2 | US State2 |

If it's not what you want, then please, edit your questions with your sample data in the form used in the `WITH` clause and show the result desired.

Comment: I will try this approach and let you know if it gets me anywhere near what I have been asked to do - thanks.